# Showing count of likes on a FB JSON feed for each post

Tags: php, json, facebook

I've been putting together a piece of PHP that pulls my organizations facebook page content and displays it dynamically on the website. Everything is working great, except for the like count. Currently my like count is only counting the likes in the first post and displaying that as the likes for every post. Here's my code:

```
<div>
<?php
$page_id = 'FacebookPage';
$access_token = 'secretaccesstoken';
$a = 0;
//Get the JSON
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/FacebookPage/posts?   access_token=secretaccesstoken');
//Interpret data
$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($fbdata->data as $post )
{
$likecount = $fbdata->data[0]->likes->data;
$posts .= '<div width="500"><div width="500" style="border: solid; border-color:    #82878e; border-width: 1px;"><h4><a href="' . $post->link .'"><img style="float: left; margin: 10;" height ="100" src="' . $post->picture . '" /></a>';
$posts .= '<a href="'. $post->link .'">' . $post->message . '</a></h4>';
$posts .= '<p>' . $post->description . '</p>';
foreach ($likecount as $likes){
$a++;
}
$posts .= '<p>' . $a . ' people like this post </p>
$a = 0;
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div> 
';
}
echo ($posts);
?>
</div>
```

I suspect that my problem is on line 13 - and that  $likecount = $fbdata->data[0]->likes->data; isn't progressing to the next segment of the data, so each time I pull the $a call it's counting the same number of likes. But I don't know how to fix it.

Any assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$fbdata->data[0]` - this will always fetch the first element of the array (i.e. first post).

So simply change `$fbdata->data[0]->likes->data;` to `$post->likes->data;`

Comment: That's WAY more elegant than what I eventually did. LOL! Thanks.